Margin note and Verbatim environment (fancyvrb)
I would like to add a margin note next to Verbatim environment, but I got the error "Not in outer par mode.".
Though this is working well with lstlisting environment.
Any solution ?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    frame=single,
    escapechar=!,
}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
text inside listings... !\marginpar{Working well}!
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single, commandchars=\\\{\}]
text inside Verbatim... \marginpar{Not working}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}


Verbatim typesets each line in a box, so \marginpar is out of question.
You can do it with marginnote; \normalfont is necessary, or you'd get typewriter type.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\newcommand{\vmnote}[1]{\marginnote{\normalfont#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single, commandchars=\\\{\}]
text inside Verbatim... \vmnote{Working}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}


For more complex text, you need to rescan the argument with standard category codes:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\vmnote}{m}
 {
  \marginnote
   {
    \normalfont % override verbatim font
    % rescan the argument with normal category codes
    \tl_rescan:nn { \cctab_select:N \c_document_cctab} { #1 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single, commandchars=\\\{\}]
text inside Verbatim... \vmnote{Working $\alpha^2$}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}


